# Taking the limit of the Solution of the Diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am currently trying to show a double limit for the convergence of the solution of the Diffusion Equation. I showed that given a PDE $u_t=u_{xx}$ and auxiliary condition $u(x,0) = g(x)$, that:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} u(x,t)=g(x)$$
Where $u(x,t)$ is given by:
$$u(x,t)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x-y,t)g(y) fy$$
And $\Phi$ is the Heat Kernel. Now, I need to show that:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0, y\rightarrow x}u(y)=g(x)$$
How do I go about solving this? I solved the case above when it was just $t\rightarrow 0$, but I don't know how to begin with solving a double limit. If anyone could help it would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The thing you've not used here is continuity (it's in $C^2$) of $u$, and that is what you must use to show this limit.

Comment: So it is about proving it first for $t\rightarrow 0$, then proving it for $y\rightarrow x$? @DaveNine

Comment: I think you're missing the point entirely, $u$ is twice differentiable as it's the solution to the diffusion equation. That limit follows trivially.

Comment: I am confused... how does the act that $u$ being twice differentiable help me find the double limit that has nothing to do with the derivatives of $u$?? @DaveNine

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity, continuity implies your limit. Don't you remember if $f$ is continuous them $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)$?

Comment: Right... Understood. So noting that $u$ is twice differentiable implies $|u(x)-u(y)|<\varepsilon$ for all $|y-x|<\delta$? (As that is the analogous statement for continuity)

Comment: Yes, and as you’ve already shown that the solution approaches the IC at the boundary, then it’s only one more line to state that starting from any point ($y$)in the domain will yield the same result because u is continuous in the spatial variable.